# Write results to csv file with two loops

Tags: python

I have the following part of the code:

```
  results=np.zeros((rules,max_n),dtype=int)
for n in v:
    print(n)
    dist=SimulationFramework(5,n,brute_force=False)
    results[:,n]=dist.distances()[:,0]
print(results)

np.save('a_5.csv', results)

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csvfilename = os.path.join(dirname, 'a_5.csv')

with open(csvfilename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|',     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for r in range(rules):
        for n in v:
            writer.writerows(r, n-3,results[r,n])
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
 TypeError: writerows() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

I am completely new to Python. I have three arguments for `writerows()`, but only one argument is taken. How can I make the code work and save the results into csv file?

Comment: [`writerows` only needs one argument.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) Why are you trying to pass it three arguments?

Comment: You need to make a list of your arguments when you write the csv row: `writer.writerow([r, n-3,results[r,n]])`

Comment: I tried it, but I get the following error:  writer.writerows([r, n-3,table_of_results[r,n]])
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you used `writerows`. If you want to use it this way you need to use `writerow` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `writerow` to write a single row with. It only accepts one argument.

```
with open(csvfilename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|',     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for r in range(rules):
        for n in v:
            writer.writerow((r, n-3,results[r,n]))
```